# Why is the logo going out border even when I include the class in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here are the HTML and CSS files I am really confused why is the border not being applied to the logo as well?
I also tried to remove the overflow property but it still shows the same output.
Can someone please tell me why is the logo going out border even when I include the class in CSS?

```css
.nav {
  color: lightcyan;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  align-content: center;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav .main_nav {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav .logo {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4b/e0/d4/4be0d42d105ba2ae4488c0ca6fae5f8a.jpg" alt="Logo" srcset="" width="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="main_nav">
    <li class="links_a"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li class="links_a"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="links_a"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="links_a"><a href="#">Blogsite</a></li>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Add to `.nav {display: flex}`. But your code is a bit wrong. You use `li` as children of a `div`. It should be `ul`.

Comment: That's it! Now works...

Comment: dont use `float` for styling purpose. float is for floating images within a text-block. It moves that element out of normal flow. as such it also does not contribute to the parents height and as such can overflow the parent. Also dont use `div class="nav"` use the semantic tag for it: `<nav>`

Comment: @Azu thankyou it worked can you please explain what exactly was the problem?

Comment: @tacoshy I will keep that in mind thankyou!

Comment: oh and by using the `nav`-tag you also dont need to give it a class. Youc an select it in CSS directly by using the `nav` as selector

Comment: https://codepen.io/tacoshy/pen/zYdmJpL <- cleanup of your code

Answer (score 0):

First, please use `ul` for the `li` tags, not `div`. You need to apply `display: flex` to the parent element `.nav` of the image and the `ul` in order to display them on one line. I've added width to the image container and to the `ul`.

```css
.nav{
    color: lightcyan;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    align-items:center ;
    align-self: center;
    align-content: center;
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
}

.nav .main_nav{
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nav .main_nav{
    display: flex;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4b/e0/d4/4be0d42d105ba2ae4488c0ca6fae5f8a.jpg" alt="Logo" srcset=""
                width="100px">
        </div>
        <ul class="main_nav">
            <li class="links_a"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li class="links_a"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="links_a"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="links_a"><a href="#">Blogsite</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "flex" property from the ".nav .logo" selector, and then add it to the navigation bar.

This is my solution:

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  color: lightcyan;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  align-content: center;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: sticky;
}    
.nav .main_nav {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}    
.nav .logo img {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the logo is floated, which allows it to extend its container. Add `overflow: auto;` to the container to avoid that:

```css
.nav {
  color: lightcyan;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  align-content: center;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: sticky;
  overflow: auto;
}

.nav .main_nav {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav .logo {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4b/e0/d4/4be0d42d105ba2ae4488c0ca6fae5f8a.jpg" alt="Logo" srcset="" width="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="main_nav">
    <li class="links_a"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li class="links_a"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li class="links_a"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="links_a"><a href="#">Blogsite</a></li>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.nav { 
  color: lightcyan; 
  border: 2px solid gray; 
  align-items: center; 
  align-self: center; 
  align-content: center; 
  top: 0; 
  position: sticky; 
  padding: 15px; 
  margin: 10px; 
  z-index: 1; 
  display: flex;
}

.nav .logo {
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 1;
}

.nav .main_nav {
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).